# The number of possible options to get colored balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a bag with 5 white balls and 3 blue balls. We getting out 3 balls (without returning).

How many possible ways is to get at least 1 white ball?

My question is why this is not the answer:
$${{5}\choose{1}}*{7 \choose 2}$$

Comment: To fail you must get a blue ball every time.

Comment: To get *atleast* 1 white ball you can do it by adding the cases of getting 1 white, out of 3; 2 whites and 3 whites. Or you can simply subtract the case of getting no white from all 3 draws.

Comment: Multiple counting. The idea behind the formula seems to be that we pick a white ball "first" and then fill in with any two balls. The product counts $W_1$ and then $W_2$ and $B_3$ as different from $W_2$ then $W_1$ and $B_3$.

Comment: Are you sure? @AndréNicolas

Comment: @Dkova: Yes, it is a standard mistake that one makes a couple of times and then probably never again. I did not write a formal answer since essentially the same issue has come up other times on MSE,, and there are a number of detailed answers, including undoubtedly one or more of mine.

Comment: @AndréNicolas can you give me a link for one?

Comment: The answer by N.F. Taussig below is good.  There are a number of similar discussions on MSE, but it is hard to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of ways of selecting $k$ of the five white balls and $3 - k$ of the three blue balls is 
$$\binom{5}{k}\binom{3}{3 - k}$$
Thus, the number of ways of selecting at least one white ball is 
$$\binom{5}{1}\binom{3}{2} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{1} + \binom{5}{3}\binom{3}{0}$$
Alternatively, we could find the same total by subtracting the number of ways of selecting zero white balls from the total number of ways of selecting three of the eight available balls.  That yields
$$\binom{8}{3} - \binom{5}{0}\binom{3}{3}$$

Why did your calculation lead to an incorrect result?

You selected one of the five white balls and two of the seven other balls.  However, this counts those selections in which more than one white ball is selected more than once.

Suppose you selected two particular white balls.  You counted each selection twice, once for each way you could have selected one of those two white balls as the white ball you selected from the five white balls while choosing the other white ball from the remaining seven balls.

You counted each selection of three particular white balls three times, once for each of the three ways you could have selected one of those three white balls as the white ball you selected from the five white balls while selecting the other two selected white balls from the remaining seven balls.

Notice that 
$$\binom{5}{1}\binom{3}{2} + 2\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{1} + 3\binom{5}{3}\binom{3}{0} = \binom{5}{1}\binom{7}{2}$$

Comment: can you explain how i count more then once?

Comment: I elaborated on my previous explanation.  Let me know if you find the explanation unclear.